# Find the way to generate the sha256Hash argument in ajax request on this website - https://dutchie.com/dispensaries/taste-buds/menu

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest, web-crawler

1. Open Chrome browser, open developer tool, switch to network tab, select XHR sub tab
2. input this URL https://dutchie.com/dispensaries/taste-buds/menu, and press refresh.
3. You will see ajax call (graphQL) to load products - https://dutchie.com/graphql?operationName=DispensaryQuery&variables=%7B%22dispensaryFilter%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22Dispensary%22%2C%22activeOnly%22%3Afalse%2C%22cNameOrID%22%3A%22taste-buds%22%7D%7D&extensions=%7B%22persistedQuery%22%3A%7B%22version%22%3A1%2C%22sha256Hash%22%3A%22bf3bcd4d9eed1d4a889037a5f2ff50332dd61b3979b900008e9af8ddbbf62f85%22%7D%7D
4. scrolling down to end to see the Query String Parameters, view parsed. You will see there is an sha256Hash argument. This value will change every 2 or 3 days.

[image: This is the request argument]

I find out the hash value is generated in this JS code. 
https://assets2.dutchie.com/vendors~main-0214ed32ab1236096fdb.bundle.js

I don't understand JS totally, anyone who can help to find the way how the hash value is generated? So i can write Python code and C# code to generate the same value.
Great thanks!